# How to convert numbers in string to another unit

Tags: android, string, integer, converters

Im trying to simply take this string and convert it to something. In my example im trying to convert some numbers that are returned from JSON, i want to convert those numbers from `12,345` to `123.45.` See code below

```
   String watts= c.getString("watts");
```

So if this was returned, lets say it was 12000 watts, I now want to convert it to KW (Kilowatts).

```
1 watt = 0.001 kilowatts
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what's your issue. Have you problem with the locale?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
String watts= c.getString("watts");
String kw = String.valueOf ( Double.parseDouble(watts)/1000 );
```

Comment: I would suggest to do `(double)Integer.parseInt(watts)/1000)` otherwise if watts is equals to 12500, it will give 12 instead of 12.5

Comment: One more thing to add, make sure to do two things, 1- try-catch the parseDouble. 2- remove any character that is not a number from the string `watts` before parsing it, otherwise it will crash. Other than that, Lucifer got it dead on.

Comment: @Lucifer Thanks for the answer, This worked perfect. LuckyMe 's answer will help me in the future as well.